Not being able to use context in ApolloServer
I can't use context on my ApolloServer instance , I'm getting
TS2353: Object literal may only specify known properties, and context does not exist in type ApolloServerOptionsWithSchema
I've tried making a custom Context interface and passing it in but it doesnt work as well
Here's the code:
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { typeDefs } from './schema/type-defs';
import { resolvers } from './schema/resolvers';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws';
import express from 'express';
import { BaseContext } from "@apollo/server";
import {expressMiddleware} from "@apollo/server/express4";
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();

// This `app` is     the returned value from `express()`.
const httpServer = createServer(app);

const schema = makeExecutableSchema(
    { typeDefs, resolvers }
);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpServer,
    path: '/graphql',
});
const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

const server = new ApolloServer<BaseContext>({  // Specify generic type here
    schema,
    context: ({ req, res })=> {
        return { req, res };
    },
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
        {
            async serverWillStart() {
                return {
                    async drainServer() {
                        await serverCleanup.dispose();
                    },
                };
            },
        }
    ],
});


(async () => {
    await server.start()
    httpServer.listen(4000, () => {
        console.log(`Query endpoint ready at http://localhost:4000/graphql`);
        console.log(`Subscription endpoint ready at ws://localhost:4000/subscriptions`);
    });
    app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), expressMiddleware(server));
})();




You're likely using Apollo server v4 but reading documents that refer to v3. The use of context is very different in the two.
In v4 context is an option of the startStandAloneServer function:
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers});
startStandaloneServer(server, { context })


I had the same problem. What worked for me was passing the context through the expressMiddleware function:
    app.use(
        "/graphql",
        cors<cors.CorsRequest>(),
        bodyParser.json(),
        expressMiddleware(server, {
            context: ({ req , res }) => {
                return { req, res };
            },
        })
    );


See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/express-middleware#example
